# How to create a graph using shell script

Tags: shell, unix, graph, visualization

I am writing data in a text file as below by running a script. This data is updated every second.

```
eth0: Sent Bytes: 1 Kb/s | Received Bytes: 2 Kb/s | Sent Packets: 18 Pkts/s | Received Packets: 13 Pkts/s
eth0: Sent Bytes: 1 Kb/s | Received Bytes: 2 Kb/s | Sent Packets: 18 Pkts/s | Received Packets: 12 Pkts/s
eth0: Sent Bytes: 1 Kb/s | Received Bytes: 3 Kb/s | Sent Packets: 20 Pkts/s | Received Packets: 13 Pkts/s
eth0: Sent Bytes: 15 Kb/s | Received Bytes: 4 Kb/s | Sent Packets: 33 Pkts/s | Received Packets: 25 Pkts/s
eth0: Sent Bytes: 1 Kb/s | Received Bytes: 3 Kb/s | Sent Packets: 19 Pkts/s | Received Packets: 12 Pkts/s
```

I want to make a graph of the # of bytes sent and the # of bytes received. Same for packets.

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: Currently, I am learning to trim the data to another file. Or directly writing a script to read data and create a graph. I dont know whether making graph directly from it will be possible!!

Comment: ok so begin it slowly and move forward with your requirement and if you are stucked give a shout on this forum.

Comment: What do you mean with *"make a graph of..."*? What sort of graph are you expecting?

Comment: I am expecting a live chart; like we see on some software for internet speed.
It is a contineous process, so I am not sure, If writing data to another file would help. I am thinking of chaning the interval to 5 seconds; and then writing the data to  a database and then pick it for graph. whats your take?

Comment: So you want a webpage? Or just some ASCII chart in a terminal? Or a GUI program..?

Comment: Just some ASCII chart to show the graph of the data.

Comment: Doesn't your OS offer this functionality anyway? `Activity Monitor` on a Mac does it for you.

Comment: Mark: I am creating a tool. and I need this functionality in that tool.

Comment: Use gnuplot. It's scriptable and can plot in both ascii and graphics

Answer (score 4):

You can use https://github.com/holman/spark to create a graph with just shell script (although it only works with `bash` and not POSIX `sh`). You can watch it update in real time with `watch`.

**graph.sh**

```
!/bin/sh
field=1
tail "$1" | cut -d '|' -f $field | sed -e 's!.*: \([0-9]\+\) .*!\1!' | ./spark/spark
```

**Interactive console**

```
git clone https://github.com/holman/spark
your-process > logfile &
watch sh graph.sh logfile
```

**Output**

```
Every 2.0s: sh graph.sh logfile          Fri Dec 19 22:22:04 2014

▁▁▁█▁
```

Comment: I'd suggest more quotes -- ie. `tail "$1"` to deal with filenames with spaces.

Comment: On Ubuntu 16.04.6, I am not seeing any output when using `watch` (the rest of the script works fine)